# How to redirect the assembly Binding, If the File not found

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried to provide the custom location for my DLL using assembly binding in app.Config file. If by mistakenly i have missed to replace that dll in to that location means its throw the file not found exception. How to overcome this by redirect the compiler to get the DLL from the bin folder

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly1"  culture="neutral" 
                          publicKeyToken="4fa4847a62640ab8"/>
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE:G:/DLL/MyAssembly1.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This is the code i have use to redirect the compiler to get DLL from the custom location

Comment: [probing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location#using-the-probing-element)?

Comment: You can't redirect to a different drive or directory that is not a subdirectory of the one in which the EXE file is stored.  A URL requires the file:// prefix.

Comment: Ant there any other way to achieve my goal.

Comment: @stuartd We can use Probing, But we only give the bin directory path inside the probing. How to provide outside directory